# Css3 circles giving blurriness

Tags: css

Im trying to use a cirlce for one of the radio button, but while using css3 im getting a blurriness around the border.

Here is the code

```
div {
    height: 18px;
    width: 18px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 50%;
   position: relative;       
    border-radius: 100px;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px -26px  inset rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    border:1px solid red;      

    }
```

Any idea how to avoid?

Comment: and how does your html looks like?

Comment: At first where is your `HTML` and why you are using `width`,`height` two times ?

Comment: provide jsfiddle or at least part of html code

Comment: You are using border-radius twice, overflow, twice, and height/width twice?

Comment: Check this https://jsfiddle.net/bp6fLo7c/

Answer (score 0):

The radio input has a margin by default, and the border of the parent div only wraps around the whole div, so the margin makes it look weird.

I set the margin of the radio button to 3px to fit it in the center. Any blur seems to be fixed in my view.

```
<div class="rad">
    <input type="radio" /> Radio Button
</div>

.rad {
    height: 18px;
    width: 18px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px -26px  inset rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    border:1px solid red;      
    overflow:hidden;
    }
input {
    margin: 3px !important;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bp6fLo7c/1/

Answer (score 0):

**You could design your own radio button.**

1) Disable default appearance :

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
appearance: none;
```

2) Style it as you want.

3) Style the "checked" state :

```
input[type="radio"]:checked {
    background-color: red;
}
```

**Demo :** https://jsfiddle.net/Paf_Sebastien/fjoyajxn/